# How to cancel google dataflow job that is stuck "cancelling"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I was trying to cancel a google dataflow job, but it has been stuck "cancelling" for like 15mins now.

When I run the command: gcloud beta dataflow jobs list --status=active

It shows the job as active. I then run the command: gcloud beta dataflow jobs cancel [job id here].

It prompts me that it has been canceled, but it still appears as active in the status list.

Comment: Disabling the API cause it to outright cancel. Any other tips I could have tried would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the job still stuck in cancelling? If you have a dataflow job ID, I can help investigate.

Comment: It is not. It stopped when I disabled the API. Wasn't anything important anyway. Thanks for the offer!

Answer (score 1):

These types of Google-end issues are best reported in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) where the engineering team responsible can be notified.

Providing further information in the issue report to Google such as your project number and the job ID of the stuck Dataflow job will help in resolving the issue more quickly.